# Вытащить из строки числа и сделать их переменными для дальнейшего использования

Tags: python

```
def draw_skeleton_data(pSkelton, index, positions, width = 4):
    start = pSkelton.SkeletonPositions[positions[0]]

    for position in itertools.islice(positions, 1, None): next = pSkelton.SkeletonPositions[position.value]
    curstart = skeleton_to_depth_image(start, dispInfo.current_w, dispInfo.current_h) 
    curend = skeleton_to_depth_image(next, dispInfo.current_w, dispInfo.current_h)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, SKELETON_COLORS[index], curstart, curend, width)
    start = next
    start_list = str(start)
```

Соответственно в этом start_list'e лежит стринговое значение, которое мне нужно в инте. 
Что выдает консоль если выводить принтом этот старт лист? (x=0.0125215521, y=0.0152125, z=0.152521521,w=1.0) Значения меняются в режиме реального времени, так как мне нужно вытащить координаты точек и вытащить их по отдельности, соответственно чтобы в итоге я получил 4 переменные x y z w.

Comment: .split(',')  и split('=')  а дальше делайте словарь

Comment: Да со сплитом оно нормально выдает, только оно еще и изначально <x= захватывает, что мне конечно же не нужно